# Why is calling a function so slow in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance

Here's something really odd I noticed recently: calling a function seems to take significantly longer than the inner function. as in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hhgs5x11/):

```
jQuery('button').click(function(){
    console.time('outer')
    dostuff.call(this)    
    console.timeEnd('outer')
})

dostuff = function(){
 console.time('inner')
 jQuery(this).css('background','red')
 jQuery(this).css('border','solid black')
 jQuery(this).css('margin','0 5px 0')
 jQuery(this).css('padding','0px')
 console.timeEnd('inner')
}
```

The console output shows the outer is WAY slower than the actual work the function does... Why does this happen, and more importantly, how can I reduce this time in time-critical code?

```
outer: timer started show:23
17:12:49.020 inner: timer started show:29
17:12:49.021 inner: 1.8ms show:34
17:12:49.023 outer: 5.1ms show:25
17:12:51.368 outer: timer started show:23
17:12:51.368 inner: timer started show:29
17:12:51.370 inner: 1.2ms show:34
17:12:51.370 outer: 2.47ms show:25
17:12:54.094 outer: timer started show:23
17:12:54.095 inner: timer started show:29
17:12:54.096 inner: 1.92ms show:34
17:12:54.098 outer: 3.67ms
```

Comment: its nice to actually see someone testing their javascript

Comment: When every millisecond counts, this stuff is really important (sarcastic) !

Comment: Not sure, but maybe the `console.time`command itself is also adding some overhead. And calling functions are indeed relatively costly in JS.

Comment: For me the difference is ~ 0.1ms. Are you sure `console.time` provides resolution/accuracy better than 1ms?

Comment: I'm getting around 0.2 milliseconds, that's almost not measurable

Comment: And this: http://jsfiddle.net/hhgs5x11/1/

Comment: In languages like C#, reflection tends to cause some overhead; it could be that using .call interferes with the ability to uniformly predict and native-compile code. Just a guess though; you'd get more accuracy by comparing 10,000 consecutive runs or something.

Comment: this is mainly jquery!

Comment: Yes, jQuery does all things ?

Comment: it goes much faster if you remove the inner console commands: http://jsfiddle.net/hhgs5x11/3/ so you're timing chrome's console, not js functions.

Comment: @saj What does that have to do with the delay calling a function?

Comment: I tried substituting `dostuff.call(this)` with its complete function body, no function call anymore and the measurement doesn't differ. I don't  think a function call in this case is a factor.

Answer (score 1):

Micro benchmarks can be very misleading, and it's why they're generally discouraged. To properly measure the timing of anything, you generally need to do a sufficient amount of meaningful work (work that causes side effects, not work that say, computes something temporarily only to discard it). Otherwise you start looking at the timing of more dynamic factors (caching, paging, a single branch misprediction, etc).

Your question is a bit too broad as answering it accurately would require exact knowledge of the internals of the precise JavaScript engine being used. We'd have to know the exact disassembly being emitted by the compiler, and when, to say for sure. Though it might help you get more accurate answers if you state the exact JavaScript engine being used.

That said, if you're using a JIT, as you probably already know, just-in-time compilers translate instructions on the fly (to bytecode IR or directly to machine code).

Some of these do translation on a per-function basis. If that's the case, you'll see the initial overhead of a first-time function call being significantly more expensive than subsequent calls, as you're paying that "first-encounter" overhead of new code being encountered by the JIT.

If you're using a trace JIT, then the JIT will be analyzing common case branches of execution ("hot paths") and you could likewise see a kind of "first-encounter" overhead in tracing code paths until a common case branch of execution is established.

Anyway, all of this is hypothetical, but it's worth noting that with many JITs, the first-time execution of code is significantly skewed in performance (much more expensive than subsequent executions of the same code). That may explain your results, or it may not.

But whatever the case may be, you generally want to steer clear of micro-benchmarks, especially with more and more dynamic factors involved (a scripting language adds a lot more than native code). We're using very complex hardware and compilers nowadays which try to predict things for us, and in the case of dynamically compiled code, we have yet one other element besides the hardware and operating system doing it on the fly. When we start measuring things at too granular of a level, combined with these dynamic factors, we cease to measure the speed of our code and instead start reverse engineering these dynamic factors.

Comment: Thanks, but I actually added `console.time`s to some working code where I noticed time spend in function was significantly more than the time spent in the function called for various elements. The Fiddle provided is a minimal case of the performance problem I was noticing, not just a "microbenchmark"

Comment: It becomes micro based on the granularity of what you are measuring rather than the broader context. Even in a real-world case, if your original measurements are doing an equal amount of work, they're micro. You generally have to analyze loopy logic to get out of that micro realm, like the cost of executing a function call a million times over.

Comment: That said, if you're using a trace JIT, then trace JITs suffer when your code has no common case branch of execution -- no hot paths, where you're branching into different code all the time. So if your real world case is, indeed, suffering from jumping into different parts of code all over the place as a result of function calls, you may be suffering one of the weaknesses of the trace JIT. Trace JITs excel when you execute the exact same code over and over with only different variables involved. They suffer a bit if you are branching into different code all the time.

Comment: then how do I get good measurements of real-world case where many elements are modified using exactly the same function - if there happen to be hundreds of elements, 100*5ms is half a second of lag!

Comment: If you update your benchmark to indicate such a case, we might be able to get to the bottom of it. It's unlikely to relate to the function call, but we need such bulky logic to properly measure where the time is actually spent.

Comment: Note that function calls never actually take 5 milliseconds or even close. That was true even when we had 16 mhz 386 machines with far inferior optimizers to what people have today. If there's ever a case where you measure 5 milliseconds from a single call, it's coming from something else (like a trace JIT encountering a new path to translate). It would take significant effort for someone even writing a toy compiler to deliberately make something so slow as to make a function call require milliseconds, like purposefully introducing a loop in the process of emitting a `CALL` instruction.

Comment: If you want to approach benchmarks that might yield useful info, you want to measure the times _outside_ the little function, inside a coarse function that does bulk processing. So, for example, you might measure the time of calling a function which just calls `do_stuff` 10k times vs. calling `do_stuff` directly 10k times. That's still not quite real world if the processing doesn't vary and yield different side effects with each iteration, but it might be enough to get to the bottom of things if the optimizer doesn't skip that work outright.

Comment: in other words, console.time isn't always reliable? What about the Profile tab?

Comment: Profiling should be more useful. It's not that console time isn't so reliable, but when you start testing a single granular operation, you can get everything from I/O overhead (depending on how the time is captured) to dynamic factors. Like even the measuring itself may start leading to different register allocation, dram access, different branches of code being executed. It's all hard to predict without a disassembly, but computers and JITs are not "static" in the sense that they give you a reliable idea of performance by just timing how long something takes...

Comment: They do a boatload of fancy things to dynamically predict what your code might do next -- from caching dram to a faster sram (and in hierarchies), predicting what branches of code are most commonly executed, paging in memory from virtual to physical addresses (on the OS side), and with JITs, you got so many more dynamic factors with how it's compiling your code on the fly. So that's kind of discomforting when you first learn about it, but you can't really tell performance very easily anymore just looking at code (even assembly). You have to time and measure it in bulk.

Comment: ... because instructions take a variable number of cycles, even at the machine instruction level. It's not, this instruction takes N cycles, it's this instruction takes between N to M cycles depending on dynamic factors (and the range could be something like 1 cycle to 100). That's just at the assembly level. The JIT adds a whole new world of dynamic factors on top. It's why even Intel uses profilers nowadays and against real world tests. Even they can't tell the performance of their own code just looking at it without tools to measure it.

Comment: And something that's really scary -- the same code could vary in speed based on where it's used. Meaning you can make a function execute more slowly by changing what's _outside_ of it without touching it -- such is the nature of the world we live in today due to all these dynamic factors (optimizers, OS, hardware) that are too hard to predict. It's why the shift is towards more and more real world testing, not micro-level measurements, and somewhat tuning with a trial and error fashion (and with the aid of a profiler).